# How to upgrade rkhunter

Tags: upgrade, updates, rkhunter

When running the command:

```
sudo rkhunter --versioncheck
```

I get the following output:

```
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.0 ]

Checking rkhunter version...
  This version  : 1.4.0
  Latest version: 1.4.2
  Update available
```

But there does not seem to be an option anywhere to upgrade `rkhunter` from version `1.4.0` to version `1.4.2`, and when running the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

There are no upgrades available for `rkhunter`, so is there some special command to upgrade it to the latest version, or is it just that I need to wait until the new version is available on the Ubuntu repositories?

I have also tried running:

```
sudo rkhunter --update
```

And I get:

```
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.0 ]

Checking rkhunter data files...
  Checking file mirrors.dat                                  [ No update ]
  Checking file programs_bad.dat                             [ No update ]
  Checking file backdoorports.dat                            [ No update ]
  Checking file suspscan.dat                                 [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/cn                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/de                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/en                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/tr                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/tr.utf8                                 [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/zh                                      [ No update ]
  Checking file i18n/zh.utf8                                 [ No update ]
```

So I assume that this is just the hash database etc and does not upgrade the actualy program version.

I am running Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The `--update` command only updates the files for the current version but does not upgrade to a newer version.
- If you want the latest rkhunter...

  - [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rkhunter/) the tar.gz file from the sourceforge project page. [Latest download is 1.4.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rkhunter/files/latest/download).
  - Go to your `~/Downloads` directory (or if you downloaded someone else to that directory) and extract the tar.gz file, `cd` into the newly created directory and install it.
  - In commands after you downloaded it ...

    ```
    cd ~/Downloads
    tar xvfz rkhunter-{tab}
    cd rkhunter-{tab}
    sudo ./installer.sh --install
    ```

    (It will automatically fill out the version number when you press <kbd>tab</kbd>.)

After this you can check the version and update the resource file with:

```
sudo rkhunter --versioncheck
sudo rkhunter --update --propupd
sudo rkhunter --checkall
```

---

Regarding the error: see `rkhunter.conf` and comment out the `SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/sbin/prelink` or install prelink (Universe needs to be enabled) with

```
sudo apt-get install prelink
```

It is disabled at install and the config file `/etc/default/prelink` needs to be changed to enabled it (`PRELINKING=yes`) but that is not needed to prevent the error.